# Resetting jsf inputText value inside a dataTable when valueChangeListener fires

Tags: jsf, datatable, icefaces

I'm using Icefaces 1.8.2 and, unfortunately, I can't change it. I have a:

```
<ice:selectOneMenu  value="#{myBean.selectedValue}" partialSubmit="true" 
       valueChangeListener="#{myBean.reloadTable}">
...
```

Then I have a dataTable:

```
<ice:dataTable  value="#{myBean.items}" var="item">
    <ice:column>
        <ice:outputText value="#{item.key}" />
    </ice:column>
    <ice:column>
        <h:inputText value="#{item.value}" />
    </ice:column>
</ice:dataTable>
```

In the bean:

```
private List<KeyValueEntry> items;

public String reloadTable(ValueChangeEvent event) {


    items=getNewItems(); //returns a list with all values set to null

    UIViewRoot view = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    return view.getViewId() + "?faces-redirect=true";
 }
```

Now the problem is the following: `items=getNewItems()` does not empty the input boxes if called from the `reloadTable(ValueChangeEvent event)`. If I write a reset method called by a `commandButton` it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The commandButton performs a Submit and redirects to the page/view you configured.

As far as I know the valueChangeListener does not by default. So you need to perform the redirect within your bean with something like:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(..)
```

Maybe `items=getNewItems()` empty your inputs but the view is not rendered again when using the Listener?

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, a missing rendering after the list update. Now, i'm using a commundButton, losing in user experience. I'll try your solution of redirect.

Comment: Just call `redirect()` as answered instead of returning string?